# How to include 2 filters in Kendo Grid?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Currently, I know there are ways to include two filter fields for Date filter in Kendo Grid UI? But the current method I have only allows one date filter to be displayed.

```
filterable: {
            ui: function (element: any) {
                element.kendoDatePicker({
                    format: "dd/MM/yyyy",
                    placeholder: "Enter Date"
                });
            },
            operators: {
                string: {
                    eq: 'Is equal to',
                    gt: 'Greater than',
                    lt: 'Less than'
                }
            }
        }
```

How can I include two date filters, one to represent the start date and one to represent the end date using this method?

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't set somewhere in your grid's definition:

```
filterable: {
  extra: false
},
```

as explained [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-filterable.extra) you should see a filter menu [with two filter fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32vRE.png). With your defined operators name you could select "greater than" for the first dropdown and "less than" for the last one.